# How to create scripts that do things on websites?

Tags: java, browser-automation

I want to create a program that performs actions on websites:
Navigate to certain pages,
Click on certain things, etc.

What are those programs called? I am just looking for a direction because right now, i have no idea what to even look for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The term you're looking for is *browser automation*, and the standard tool for it is [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org). I personally prefer [Geb](http://www.gebish.org) as a DSL layer on top of Selenium.